# Disassociated WLAN (Disassociated due to inactivity)

Tags: networking, radius, freeradius, access-point

I am reading the logs provided by an access point I have broadcasting an 802.11i (WPA) LAN network running with a radius authentication method, and the log returns the following two messages:

```
Aug 31 10:09:54 10.100.1.78 CONN-LOGIN_INFO: [WLAN-1] Disassociated WLAN station 78:b8:d6:71:25:21 due to station request: Disassociated due to inactivity
Aug 31 10:09:54 10.100.1.78 CONN-LOGIN_INFO: [WLAN-1] Deauthenticated WLAN station 78:b8:d6:71:25:21: Disassociated due to inactivity
Aug 31 10:09:57 10.100.1.78 CONN-LOGIN_INFO: [WLAN-1] Authenticated WLAN station 78:b8:d6:71:25:21: algorithm is open-system
Aug 31 10:09:57 10.100.1.78 CONN-LOGIN_INFO: [WLAN-1] Local access check for 78:b8:d6:71:25:21 succeeded
Aug 31 10:09:57 10.100.1.78 CONN-LOGIN_INFO: [WLAN-1] Associated WLAN station 78:b8:d6:71:25:21
Aug 31 10:09:57 10.100.1.78 CONN-LOGIN_INFO: [WLAN-1] WLAN station 78:b8:d6:71:25:21 has cached PMK, skip 802.1x
Aug 31 10:09:57 10.100.1.78 CONN-LOGIN_INFO: [WLAN-1] Key handshake with peer 78:b8:d6:71:25:21 successfully completed
Aug 31 10:09:57 10.100.1.78 CONN-LOGIN_INFO: [WLAN-1] Connected WLAN station 78:b8:d6:71:25:21
Aug 31 10:09:57 10.100.1.78 CONN-LOGIN_INFO: [WLAN-1] Determined IPv4 address for station 78:b8:d6:71:25:21: 10.100.0.6
Aug 31 10:09:57 10.100.1.78 CONN-LOGIN_INFO: [WLAN-1] Determined IPv6 address for station 78:b8:d6:71:25:21: fe80::b61d:b2ec:c702:1cb4
```

Four android devices are connected to the network provided by the access point, and this error always occurs on one or two of them, it never occurs on all of them at the same time.

I don't know if it could be due to some specific parameter of the radius configuration or the configuration of the access point itself, could someone explain me why this error occurs?

Thanks.